# webpack's css-loader has an options 'localIdentName', is there anything else other than ' [hash:base64]'?

Tags: hash, webpack, css-loader

Such as [hash:MD5] [hash:SHA]. I have seen the css-loader readme document, where there is no relevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `localIdentName` has some options like `base32`, `base16`, `hex` and etc.

But I believe best of them is `base64`, you can write like this:

`sha512:hash:base64:5`

for more information you can read [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/101)